# Does someone know why does DosBox giving me this error?

Tags: assembly, dosbox

when I run this code in DosBox:
`tasm /zi base.asm`

it gives me this error:
`Fatal base.asm(7) Unexpected end of file encountered`

this is my code:

```
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
DATASEG
var db ?
CODESEG
start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    mov [var], 5
exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
END start
```

It should run on Turbo Assembler.
I tried to check if there is any errors in the end of the file end founf and found nothig...
I'm new to Assembly so maybe you can see somthing that I cant...

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact file you are using? It does not end on line 7... Also it assembles fine for me.

Comment: It is the correct file, I also wondered why DosBox gave me this error on line 7...
My DosBox runs on my M1 mac, do you think that the M1 is the problem?

Comment: Make sure you have the correct line endings and no unprintable characters. Maybe create a new file for testing.

Comment: DOSBox is an emulator written in C.  From the perspective of your M1 CPU or an x86 CPU, it's just another C program compiled to native asm.  Running on an x86 host isn't particularly special for DOSBox, AFAIK.

Comment: FWIW, I've had the djgpp version of gcc bomb out with "internal compiler error" several times on dosbox. Maybe try dosbox-x, which seems to be more compliant.

Comment: I doubt the M1 is the problem, as x86-64 isn't capable of natively running 8086 code either, yet it manages just fine.